# Prove that $3\cdot 5^{2n+1} +2^{3n+1}$ is divisible by $17$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Use mathematical induction to prove that $3\cdot 5^{2n+1} +2^{3n+1}$
>   is divisible by $17$ for all $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$.

I've tried to do it as follow.

If $n = 1$ then  $392/17 = 23$.
Assume it is true when $n = p$. Therefore $3\cdot 5^{2p+1} +2^{3p+1} = 17k $ where $k ∈ \mathbb{N} $. Consider now $n=p+1$. Then 
\begin{align}
&3\cdot 5^{2(p+1)+1} +2^{3(p+1)+1}=\\
&3\cdot 5^{2p+1+2} + 2^{3p+1+3}=\\
&3\cdot5^{2p+1}\cdot  5^{2} + 2^{3p+1}\cdot 2^{3}.
\end{align}
I reached a dead end from here. If someone could help me in the direction of the next step it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When $n=p$ you assume that $3\cdot 5^{2p+1}+2^{3p+1} = 17k$, don't you?

Comment: You did. I just corrected the notation for products.

Comment: This won't help you if you have to use explicit induction for classroom purposes, but it's much quicker to prove this directly: $$ 3\cdot 5^{2n+1} + 2^{3n+1} = 15\cdot 25^n + 2\cdot 8^n$$ and since $25\equiv 8\pmod{17}$ this is congruent to $(15+2)8^n \equiv 0\pmod{17}$.

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032384/how-do-i-prove-11-mid-26n132n-2-by-induction/2032490#2032490  OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168065/proof-by-induction-divisibility-by-5/2168143#2168143 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258457/proving-that-3n7n2-is-divisible-by-12-for-all-n-in-mathbbn/2258491#2258491  or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497585/prove-by-induction-that-if-this-is-divisible-by-11-then-this-is-also-divisible/2497627#2497627

Comment: Hey, can this question be proved using modular arithmetic?

Comment: @MagedSaeed Yes, it's very easy using mod - see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having shown that
$$3\cdot5^{2p+1}+2^{3p+1}=17k$$
we have (continuing from the last line)
$$3\cdot5^{2p+1}5^{2}+2^{3p+1}2^{3}=17(3\cdot5^{2p+1})+8(3\cdot5^{2p+1}+2^{3p+1})=17(3\cdot5^{2p+1}+8k)$$
so the next expression is also divisible by 17, as required.

Comment: Can you please help me understand how you got into the second step because thats the step i cant understand. Thanks

Comment: @ShehanTearz $3\cdot5^{2p+1}\cdot5^2=3\cdot5^{2p+1}\cdot17+3\cdot5^{2p+1}\cdot8$. Then I rearrange and collect the two terms with 8.

Comment: @ShehanTearz It's harder to undertstand this was because the *arithmetical* essence of the inductive step is highly obfuscated.. But we *can* present it in a way that shows clearly that it amounts to scaling by $\,\,\color{#c00}{5^{\large 2} \equiv\, 2^{\large 3}}\pmod{\!17}\,\,$ in order bump the powers of $5$ and $3,\,$  see my answer.

Answer (score 4):

*Conceptually* the inductive step scales by $\,\color{#c00}{5^{\large 2} \equiv\, 2^{\large 3}}\pmod{\!17}.\,$ If you don't know congruences we can preserve this *arithmetical* essence by using a **divisibility (vs. congruence) product rule** where we used standard notation $\ m\mid n\ $ means $\,m\,$ divides $\,n.\,$

$$\qquad\ \  \begin {align}
&17\mid\ \ \ \color{#c00}{5^{\large 2}\quad\ \ -\quad\ \  2^{\large 3}}\\
&17\mid\ a\ \ \ 5^{\large 2n+1} -\ b\ \ \ \,2^{\large 3n+1}\qquad\ P(n)\\
\Rightarrow\ \ &17\mid a \color{#c00}{5^{\large 2}} 5^{\large 2n+1}\! -\,\ b \color{#c00}{2^{\large3}} 2^{\large 3n+1}\qquad P(n\!+\!1)
\end{align} $$

$\begin{align}{\bf Divisibility\ Product\ Rule}\ \ \ \  
&m\mid\  a\ -\ b\qquad {\rm i.e.}\quad \   a\,\equiv\, b\\
&m\mid \ \ A\: -\: B\qquad\qquad \ A\,\equiv\, B\\
\Rightarrow\ \ &\color{}{m\mid aA - bB}\quad  \Rightarrow\quad aA\equiv bB\!\pmod{\!m}\\[.2em]
{\bf Proof}\,\ \  m\mid (\color{#0a0}{a\!-\!b})A + b(\color{#0a0}{A\!-\!B}) &\,=\, aA-bB\ \ \text{by $\,m\,$ divides $\rm\color{#0a0}{green}$ terms by hypothesis.}\end{align}$

You can find further discussion in [many prior posts.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a242%20%22divisibility%20product%20rule%22)

Comment: Bill.Thank you for your comment . A much deeper understanding of the elements involved than my adhoc juggling with numbers.Chapeau! Nice, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Step $n+1:$

$3(5^2)5^{2p+1}+(2^3)2^{3p+1}=$

$3(17+8)5^{2p+1} +8 \cdot 2^{3p+1}=$

$8[3 \cdot 5^{2p+1}+2^{3p+1}]+ 17\cdot 3 \cdot 5^{2p+1}.$

The first term in the above sum is divisible by $17$ (hypothesis), the second term is a multiple of $17$.

Comment: If you do it in reverse order then you can view it as scaling $P(n)$ by  $\, 5^2\equiv 2^{\large 3}\pmod{\!17}$ in order to send $\,n\mapsto n+1$ in the powers $\, 5^{\large 2n}\,$ and $\,2^{\large 3n},\,$ to obtan $\,P(n+1).\,$ I explain this *arithmetical* viewpoint in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two alternative routes.

Using the binomial theorem:
$$
3\cdot 5^{2n+1} +2^{3n+1}
= 15\cdot 25^{n} +2\cdot 8^{n}
= 15\cdot (17+8)^{n} +2\cdot 8^{n}\\
= 15\cdot (17a+8^{n}) +2\cdot 8^{n}
= 17b+15\cdot 8^{n} +2\cdot 8^{n}
= 17b+17\cdot 8^{n}
$$

Using recurrences:

Let
$
x_n=3\cdot 5^{2n+1} +2^{3n+1}
$,
Since, as above,
$
x_n= 15\cdot 25^{n} +2\cdot 8^{n}
$,
we have the recurrence $x_{n}=33x_{n-1}-200x_{n-2}$, for $n\ge 2$ (*).
The result follows by induction because $x_0$ and $x_1$ are multiples of $17$.

(*) In general, if $x_n=a\alpha^{n} +b\beta^{n}$, then $x_{n}=(\alpha+\beta)x_{n-1}-(\alpha\beta)x_{n-2}$, for $n\ge 2$. This follows because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the quadratic $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=x^2-(\alpha+\beta)x+(\alpha\beta)$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with the inductive step

$$3\cdot5^{2(n+1)+1}+2^{3(n+1)+1}$$

$$3\cdot5^{2n+1+2}+2^{3n+1+3}$$

$$3\cdot25\cdot5^{2(n+1)}+8\cdot2^{3n+1}$$

We know that $$3\cdot5^{2n+1}+2^{3n+1}=17k$$

Therefore $$3\cdot5^{2n+1}=17k-2^{3n+1}$$

Plug this in: 
$$25\cdot(17k-2^{3n+1})+8\cdot2^{3n+1}$$

$$425k\cdot-25\cdot2^{3n+1}+8\cdot2^{3n+1}$$

$$425k\cdot-17\cdot2^{3n+1}$$

$$17(25-2^{3n+1})$$